# External library to Clion (armadillo)

Tags: c++, clion, armadillo

I am looking to use armadillo in Clion. I used homebrew to install on my mac, but am having difficulty including the library in my executable, when using `#include <armadillo>`. I am getting "armadillo file not found." How can I mitigate this issue?

I am new to the external library game in C++, as I've only ever used the STL. If I am trying to create a large project in C++, is there a better, possibly more portable IDE I should be using? (Side question)

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Are you using CMake? Otherwise you will have to tell your compiler where to find the armadillo files using parameters

Comment: Tbh I don't know. There is a Cmakelist.txt file...Do you know how I can find this out?